# Why do I have so many verticies hidden under one point?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

So I am trying to create this eye and noticed that whenever I try to move the vertex inwards it has like 4 more vertices underneath.

You can see I tried to use the grab tool and it took 4 tries just to get to the final vertex

[image]

Note I used snap to faces mode for this

But even when I use wireframe it shows only one dot?

Is this normal when using snap to faces or how do I remove all these extra verticies?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In edit mode if you select all then press M and select merge by distance it will clean up any doubles.

also if you box select all the verts that are affected you can press M and select Merge at Centre

Comment: why did it create multiple vertexes in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

In some cases, Blender creates new vertices, then you are not expected to. For example, then you extrude polygons and then cancel the operation. In this case, you cancel only moving vertices, but not creating additional polygons. This make sense, then you extrude, cancel translate and then scale.

In your picture, you can detect that point is doubled, because Blender highlight edges that connected to selected points. As you see, Blender doesn't highlight one edge, that means this point is not connected directly to that edge.

[image]

Then you are using snap to point, you can auto merge vertices. To do that check auto merge option in tool settings:

[image]

Tool settings toggles here:

[image]

You can also use merge by distance <kbd>M</kbd> → By Distance

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the auto-merge toggle